# How do I test for autocorrelation on my unsorted panel-data?

Tags: r, panel-data, plm, autocorrelation

I want to test my panel-data for autocorrelation. It does not matter a lot which test I do, but it has to be included in my report and I am unsure which package and function to use. Below I show some of my data. I have a data-point for every year 1989-2003 for 25 countries. The dependent variable is battle deaths and the independent variables are GDP, Population etc.

I was thinking about using the plm package and the pdwtest function. However, this function needs to have an object panelmodel as imput. Can I convert my dataframe into this? Or is there another function I could use?

````
conflict_id nr_groups year    location_inc bdbest GDP_capita_lag GDP_capita Population Polity_score Polity_lag   logGDP logPopulation
1            0         0 1989            Iran      0           4796       4841      54479           -6         -6 8.484877     10.905571
2            0         1 1989     Philippines    937           3239       3456      63555            8          8 8.147867     11.059661
3            0         1 1989 Myanmar (Burma)   1194            981        992      38721           -6         -6 6.899723     10.564137
4            0         1 1989           India    977           1168       1228     822000            8          8 7.113142     13.619496
5            0         1 1989       Guatemala     82           3329       3521       8731            3          3 8.166500      9.074635
6            0         2 1989          Israel     54          20608      20147       4355            6          6 9.910811      8.379080
7            0         2 1989            Iraq     50           8602       7491      17568           -9         -9 8.921458      9.773834
8            0         1 1989        Ethiopia  24358           1036       1022      50128           -8         -8 6.929517     10.822335
9            0         0 1989           Nepal      0           1006       1067      18173           -2         -2 6.972606      9.807692
10           0         0 1989         Burundi      0           1346       1270       5382           -7         -7 7.146772      8.590815```
````

Comment: Asking for suggestions on packages/libraries/functions is close to [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): *"recommend or find a book, tool, software library"*, but I think a more appropriate recommendation to you would be to have this question migrated to [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/), where the academic discussion is more appropriate.

Comment: Autocorrelation is not about the original data. It is about the residuals of an estimated model. Based on the research question, pose an appropriate model first, estimate it and then look at its residuals.